# RxSwift Way To Map and Bind UITextView's Text to Custom Object's text field?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I know I can do the following to map changes to a custom object's Notes' text field to a UITextView.

```
self.notesViewModel.currentNote()
           .map { $0.text }
           .bindTo(self.notesTextView.rx_text)
```

How can I do the reverse using the same kind of pattern? The pattern is notesTextView.rx_text, map it to the current note's text. I know how to do the following which feels non-RxSwift-y:

```
_ = notesTextView.rx_text.subscribeNext { someText in
    self.notesViewModel.currentNote().value.text = someText
}
```

IOW, it seems like I should be able to take the UITextView (aka notesTextView), map, and bind changes into the current note. Current note returns a Variable with a Note having a text String field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `<->` two way binding operator.

There's a nice [example in the RxSwift repo](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/GitHubSignup/Views/GitHubSignupViewController.swift#L24), here's a usage example:

```
// bind UI values to variables
usernameOutlet.rx_text <-> username
passwordOutlet.rx_text <-> password
repeatedPasswordOutlet.rx_text <-> repeatedPassword
```

Comment: It's a great operator and warrants being pointed out. Great job providing a link to the GitHubSignupViewController file that contains it.

Comment: After placing the function into place, I tried notesTextView.rx_text <-> self.notesViewModel.currentNote().text and I get the error: "Cannot convert value of type 'ControlProperty<String>' to expected argument type 'ControlProperty<_>'

Comment: For RxSwift 2.2 : https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Operators.swift#L20

Comment: @thierryb can not make it work. Get all the time `Cannot convert value of type 'ControlProperty<String>' to expected argument type 'ControlProperty<_>'`

Comment: @orkenstein UIControl.rx_text <-> ObservableProperty

Comment: in RxSwift 3.x this must be 
usernameOutlet.rx.textInput <-> username
passwordOutlet.rx.textInput <-> password
repeatedPasswordOutlet.rx.textInput <-> repeatedPassword

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this between a textField and variable of dissimilar types, I've submitted the solution I came up with using tuples and closures as a pull request:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/pull/559

The same method could be used to map a Double to a String for example.